# What is this bush with five-petalled white flowers?

Tags: identification

More importantly, is it poison oak? It has 3 leaves... It's located in Maryland.

*<sub>Click photo for full size</sub>*

[image: flowering bush]

Comment: Probably not PO, based on this site's pictures. http://phc.amedd.army.mil/PHC%20Resource%20Library/AtlanticPoisonOak-JusttheFactsJuly2007.pdf

Comment: Looks more wild strawberryish. I'm not convinced tho: https://www.google.com/search?q=wild+strawberry+identify&biw=1408&bih=696&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mHZiVYDMFcqlsAXfwIFI&ved=0CCsQsAQ#tbm=isch&q=wild+strawberry+plants

Comment: From looking at pictures, the flower petals look a little too oval (instead of round) and have 6 petals instead of 5. The leaves look a little too pointed (rather than rounded) for strawberry. Though, that was my first thought as well. As to Poison Oak, the flowers of that are grown in clusters of tiny yellow flowers and the leaves would be more lobed rather than toothed, so definitely not that either.

Comment: Looks a lot like some Rubus - blackberry or raspberry. Will elaborate later.

Comment: Could you clarify please: How many petals does each flower have? I see five *and* six, but the picture is a bit unclear.

Comment: Any thorns on any of the stems? I think I might be able to see one or two on the stem in the foreground, slightly to the right at the bottom of this picture, but none on the other stem I can see.

Answer (score 1):

It looks somewhat like Rubus flagellaris - that should have scattered prickles here and there on the stems, but this looks a bit too bushy, as if its been cut back - this plant usually puts out a long stem rather than becoming a bushy plant. Photo in link below:

http://uswildflowers.com/detail.php?SName=Rubus%20flagellaris

Comment: Northern dewberry: http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=RUFL

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger There's better pics on line - that one only shows it with a berry, there are others showing the flowers - listed as a weed in Maryland.

Comment: Or maybe not Maryland!